# Angular, access JSON elements with special character

Tags: json, angular

I have the json String as follows, how to access the elements,

I tried 
responsePdiJson.xs:schema or responsePdiJson.'xs:schema' none works

```
{  
   "xs:schema":{  
      "$":{  
         "elementFormDefault":"qualified",
         "targetNamespace":"urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0",
         "version":"1.0",
         "xmlns:xs":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      },
      "xs:element":[  
         {  
            "$":{  
               "name":"Calls"
            },
            "xs:complexType":[  
               {  
                  "xs:sequence":[  
                     {  
                        "$":{  
                           "maxOccurs":"unbounded"
                        },
                        "xs:element":[  
                           {  
                              "$":{  
                                 "name":"Call"
                              },
```

Below is the function that i used to convert xml to JSON

```
 let res: any;
     parseString(response.body, function (err, result) {          
      res = JSON.stringify(result)
      console.dir(result);
      return res;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it with,

```
responsePdiJson["xs:schema"];
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myObj = {
  "xs:schema": {
    "$": {
      "elementFormDefault": "qualified",
      "targetNamespace": "urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0",
      "version": "1.0",
      "xmlns:xs": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    },
    "xs:element": [
      {
        "$": {
          "name": "Calls"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(myObj["xs:schema"]);
```